# Unable to update items in bulk using a Content Provider. IllegalArgumentException is being thrown

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

So I've been trying to update SMSes in bulk by sending an array of message IDs as the selection argument. However, it's throwing an IllegalArgumentException.

Here's the code:

```
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues(1);
    contentValues.put(SMSUtils.READ, 1);

    String selection = SMSUtils._ID + "=?";

    int mRowsUpdated = contentResolver.update(
            CONTENT_URI_SMS,
            contentValues,
            selection,
            messageIds  // array of message IDs
    );
```

and the **exception**:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too many bind arguments.  7 arguments were provided but the statement needs 2 arguments.`

An alternative to this is to use a loop and update messages in sequence, but I think that will be slower. Any ideas?